# Creating user profile after they sign up

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm using Django Allauth. Users can either sign up using Google, Twitter, Facebook or they can sign up using their email address. Once signed up, their details will be stored in the `User` table. There's also another model I have called `Profile` that contains user information like `bio, avatar, etc.` I'd like to create a Profile for the user when they sign up. I looked at Allauth signals and found the `user_signed_up` signal to be appropriate. Here's how I wrote the code in my `handlers.py` file:

```
@receiver(user_signed_up)
def create_profile(request, user):
    profile = Profile(avatar='img/blah/blah.jpg',  bio='Example text', gender='M', dob='2018-01-01',
                      country='US', user=user)
    profile.save()
```

I added random stuff just so I can see if it's being created or not, but for some reason when the user signs up their profile is not being created. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure you're importing the `handlers.py` module somehow in order to signal handler gets registered, you can write

```
 import handlers
```

anywhere in your code, but the recommended place is in the `ready` method of your app config class.

References:

https://chriskief.com/2014/02/28/django-1-7-signals-appconfig/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/applications/

Comment: Hmm, I just have a couple of questions. Do I need to put anything in init.py? It seems like it is working without putting the `default_app_config` there. Also, let's say I have another signal in another app and let's say the current app uses that other app's model to insert data, will the signal still be called even though it is in another app?

Comment: If your `handlers` module will be in another directory, yes, you will have to add an `__init__.py` in order to make that directory a package, if it is located in the same directory that the file importing it, is not mandatory (but recommended). And yes, the signal still be called even though it is in another app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write signal when user model instance save signal will work there you need to write one condition this instance is new created or old modify base on this condition you can create profile

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def user_updated(sender, created=False, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs.get('instance', None)
    if user and created:
        ##create profile object here
```